# excel vba to delete blank rows in a range across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to delete rows in the range from 7 to 31 if the data in column A is blank.  However i  want this to run all worksheets other than the ones i specify.  I have attempted the code but it doesn't work, can anyone give me a pointer on where i went wrong?  Also should i be putting an error handling  for if there isn't any blank cells?

```
Sub deletespaces()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Menu" And ws.Name <> "Paste here" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then

 Range("a7:A31").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid `Select`.
2. Qualify the `Range` with the worksheet `ws`.
3. Test first for blank cells.

```
If ws.Name <> "Menu" And ws.Name <> "Paste here" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
    Dim visibleCells As Range  
    Set visibleCells = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set visibleCells = ws.Range("a7:A31").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not visibleCells Is Nothing Then
        visibleCells.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If
```

Comment: thanks big ben so how would i get this to loop through my worksheets?  I tried adding it  after the then on the original code but got  "next without  for"

Comment: Probably missing an `End If`... see the edit for what the code inside the loop should be.

Comment: i am now getting a runtime error 91 object variable or with  block variable not set

Comment: On what line please?

Comment: Sorry BigBen i mistyped a worksheet name and that was what created the error.  Really appreciate your help